# d3js drag a text from html DOM and add it to SVG on drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js, svg

As I am learning d3js I am trying to make a small program where there are (planets in solar system) as texts in the HTML DOM and there are ellipses(rings) around a circle (sun). I need to be able to drag the text and as they are dropped it should identify on which ellipse and append into the group. For now, it does not need to check if the location is correct just want to append a circle when the text gets dropped into the circle.

I looked at some Jquery UI and other samples, but I am not having much luck on this issue.

```js
var svg = d3.select('body')
  .append("svg")
  .attr("id", "program")
  .attr("height", 500)
  .attr("width", 500);

var sun = svg.append("circle")
  .attr("cx", 250)
  .attr("cy", 250)
  .attr("r", 25)
  .attr("fill", "orange");

var mercg = svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("id", "mercury")
  .append("ellipse")
  .attr("class", "droppable")
  .attr("cx", 250)
  .attr("cy", 250)
  .attr("rx", 55)
  .attr("ry", 45)
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "black");

var venus = svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("id", "venus")
  .append("ellipse")
  .attr("class", "droppable")
  .attr("cx", 250)
  .attr("cy", 250)
  .attr("rx", 85)
  .attr("ry", 65)
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "black");

var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
  .on("drag", dragged)
  .on("dragend", dragend);

function dragged(d) {
  d3.select(this).attr("cx", d3.event.x).attr("cy", d3.event.y);
}

function dragend(d) {
  // Here, How do i find on what ring the item was dropped?
  // I want the circle to be on the selected ring group
}

var ex = svg.append("circle")
  .attr("transform", 'translate(0,0)')
  .attr("cx", 279)
  .attr("cy", 212)
  .attr("r", 10)
  .attr("fill", "blue")
  .call(drag);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <ul>
    <li draggable="true" ondragstart="drag()" class="draggable"> Mercury</li>
    <li draggable="true" class="draggable">Venus </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In the end I am looking for something that looks like the image produced at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/tomatetz/bvcry3qb/)

You can drag-n-drop html to svg and find drop target. Now you can add `if` statement to detect if target is ellipse. Also you can add additional ellipse to each existing ellipses with `opacity 0` and wider `stroke-width` parameter to avoid pixel hunting.

update: [new fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tomatetz/bvcry3qb/1/) you can drag-n-drop HTML elements to svg orbits and new circle will append (if you drop planet name on its orbit)

Comment: Do you know why i the previous code i am not able to get the group name when the item is dropped? `var venus = svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("id", "venus")
  .append("ellipse")...`. This does not return the id of the group `venus`

Comment: you mean in `dragend(d) {` function? You can use `d3.select(this);` or `d3.event` there